# Get term value from a listitem and set it to another listitem via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, taxonomy, term-set

I first I get a site/listitem and store it in variable $page.

```
$category = $page.FieldValues["myTermField"];
```

In above, I get the term-value in the field "myTermField" and store it in $category.

I then want to set the value of the $category variable to another field. I tried:

```
 Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Identity @myOtherPage -Values @{"myOtherTermField" = $($category);  }
```

Above does not work. I have tried to put the data in a text-column and it works - I get the term as Label|GUID. However, I want to put all in a managed metadata column and that does not work. I get the error "value cannot be empty".

I also tried:

```
 Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue -ListItem @myOtherPage  -InternalFieldName "myOtherTermField" -Terms @category
```

Above does not work. Get the error:

> Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue : Cannot bind parameter 'TermId'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Clien
>   t.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" to type "SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PipeBinds.GuidPipeBind".

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$myOtherTermField = $category -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the same question posted by you in another Technet Thread, please remember to check it:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/de7406b9-c64d-43c8-97fd-84c7fc88cafe/set-terms-as-value-to-a-list-field-via-powershell?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

You could try the following code, which works for me:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Identity 1 -Values @{"myOtherTermField" = $category.termguid}
```